# .htaccess 404 page for invalid subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

is there a way to make a custom error page for an invalid subdomain in the .htaccess file? I would like visitors to have a way back to the homepage if they intentionally or unintentionally type an invalid subdomain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes** it is possible.

If you run your subdomain as a seperate server, then you have to edit the .htaccess file on the particular server. Otherwise you can edit the .htaccess file on the same one to setup its error pages. Furthermore you have to know that an apache2 server uses the first virtual host you configure if there is no matching name, so you are able to setup the virtual host and return the 404 page.

Good tutorials for setting up virtual hosts:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/
http://www.unixmen.com/setup-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-15-10/
https://serversforhackers.com/configuring-apache-virtual-hosts

I hope this helps :-)